# JavaScript session cookies - remove when tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

My widget relies on a unique session cookie being set that identifies each visitor.

Currently i am setting a cookie which is deleted when the user closes the browser, however.. If the user closes the tab instead of the entire browser the cookie is not being removed.

Is there any way to remove the cookie when the tab is closed?

Edit: Cookie still has to be set when user reloads the actual page only want to delete if they close the tab.

So the unload event is not an option here as it would delete the cookie when the page reloads

Answer (score -1):

On unload, set the time of unload in the cookie. When the page (re)loads, check to see if the time was very recent. If it isn't recent, (i.e. not a page reload), delete the cookie and start afresh. Obviously being a session cookie, it will be properly deleted either way once the browser is closed, and this way when the tab is closed, the data is ignored as if it were deleted.

Comment: How would a code snippet for that look like? Not sure i follow